# Resampling/time groupby to a specific time span/period

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm attempting group some data into four-weekly buckets, and using the `pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='4W')`. I want the groups to be such that if I have 8-weeks of data from say 2019-08-26 to 2019-10-20 for the first group to range from 2019-08-26 to 2019-09-22 and the second group to range from 2019-09-23 to 2019-10-20. However when using the grouper, it does not group in this way, rather it anchors to the first Sunday and calculates four weeks from there producing output like this:

```py
created_at
2019-09-01    317
2019-09-29    990
2019-10-27    645
Freq: 4W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

instead of:

```py
created_at
2019-08-26    1048
2019-09-23     904
Freq: 4W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

The other option I've tried is to use `pd.Timedelta(weeks=4)` as the frequency, like so:

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq=pd.Timedelta(weeks=4)).size()
```

However this only works if all the dates are available in the data. If the data doesn't start until 2019-08-30 for instance the group labels are different because it is calculating a delta from the earliest date. I am considering creating a custom offset object but not sure if this is the right direction.

The raw data looks roughly like this:

```
                created_at
id
4324856 2019-08-26 12:38:51
4325472 2019-08-26 13:18:07
4325974 2019-08-26 13:47:09
4326205 2019-08-26 13:56:27
4326296 2019-08-26 13:57:35
```

with additional columns that are not relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: what does your raw input look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add argument `closed='left'` in [pd.Grouper()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper). By default, the closed end of interval is `'right'`

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='4W', closed='left')).size()
```